# MassTransit - Send & Publish : in between

Tags: multi-tenant, masstransit

I have understood the difference between Send (~1 consumer called) & Publish (all consumers called). In my environment I would like something in between.

**For exemple :**

A parcel is prepared and ready to be shipped. An event can be sent "ParcelPrepared". On this event, 2 actions should be triggered : "Build Invoice" & "Send Email". But each actions should be called only once.

Actually I only managed to do that with a Send and both actions are hosted in the same .net process (but I don't want that). If each actions is hosted on different process, only one of them will be triggered.

If I use Publish, all process will be called and I could send *N* emails or build *N* invoices, and I will lost messages if the process are down.

Did I missed something ?

**EDIT:**

Here is schema of what I would like to achieve.

[image: Objective]

Many process "Parcel Preparation" can emit a message (command/event I don't know) "Parcel Prepared".

Different consumers ("Invoicing" and "Email Sender") wants to be notified when the message is emitted. Each consumer is instanciated multiple times. Only one of each consumer should be notified to avoid to handle concurrency on each consumer.

Each consumer should be able to receive the missed messages if they are down some reason, even if only part of consumer are down ("Invoicing" up and "Email Sender" down, both down).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ParcelPrepared` is an event and it should be **published**. You then can have two consumers in those different processes, that will **send** commands `BuildInvoice` and `SendEmail`. Consumers of those commands will do the work.

You never lose messages since they are placed to endpoint queues and will stay there until consumed.

Comment: Thanks @alexey-zimarev.

Comment: But a few question to understand it well : 

- what if event consumers are down, because event queues are not durable, the event will be lost and not processed when they will be back up

- what if I have I have multiple instance of each process, it will send duplicates of the command, isn't it ?

Comment: event queues should be durable. as are the subscriptions for those queues to the message types defined by your receive endpoints.

Comment: If have edited my question to include a schema to be more explicit.

From my readings and my understanding, for Publishing, each process create an auto-delete queue attached to the common exchange.

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev Do you have any idea or pattern on how to do that with MassTransit ?

Comment: @luke77 It is all straightforward; if you have issues - please join the MassTransit Gitter and we can discuss it.